# Удаление элементов бинарного дерева

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево

Элемент дерева:

```
typedef struct tree{
    char * word;
    struct tree *left,*right;
}TREE;

#define NL 7
```

Нужно удалить все элементы, для которых длина `word >= NL`
Функция удаления одного элемента:

```
#define NoSubTree    0
#define LeftSubTree -1
#define RightSubTree 1
#define TwoSubTrees  2

void deleteNode(char* word, TREE** his_root)
{
    TREE* proot = *his_root, * new_root, *ppar;
    int cmp, substr, word_l, root_l;

    if (proot == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    cmp = strcmp(proot->word, word);
    word_l = strlen(word);
    root_l = strlen(proot->word);

    if (cmp == 0)
    {
        if (proot->left == NULL && proot->right == NULL)
        {
            substr = NoSubTree;
        }
        else if (proot->right == NULL)
        {
            substr = LeftSubTree;
        }
        else if (proot->left == NULL)
        {
            substr = RightSubTree;
        }
        else
        {
            substr = TwoSubTrees;
        }

        switch (substr)
        {
            case NoSubTree:
                *his_root  = NULL;
                break;

            case LeftSubTree:
                *his_root = proot->left;
                break;

            case RightSubTree:
                *his_root = proot->right;
                break;

            case TwoSubTrees:
                new_root = proot->left;
                ppar = proot;

                while (new_root->right != NULL)
                {
                    ppar = new_root;
                    new_root = new_root->right;
                }

                new_root->right = proot->right; // присоединяем правое поддерево

                if (new_root != proot->left)  //если не вершина левого поддерева
                {
                    ppar->right = new_root->left;
                    new_root->left = proot->left; // присоединяем левое поддерево
                }

                *his_root = new_root;//замена корня
                freeNode(proot);
                return;
        }
    }

    if (root_l > word_l || (cmp > 0 && root_l == word_l))
    {
        deleteNode(word, &proot->left);
    }

    if (word_l > root_l || (cmp < 0 && root_l == word_l))
    {
        deleteNode(word, &proot->right);
    }
}
```

Проход по дереву и поиск подходящих слов (`root` - глобальный указатель на корень).

```
void search_words(TREE* proot)
{
    if (proot == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    search_words(proot->right);

    if (strlen(proot->word) >= NL)
    {
        deleteNode(proot->word, &root);
    }

    search_words(proot->right);
}
```

Удаление 1 элемента работает, как я понимаю, проблема именно в поиске слов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вдаваясь в само удаление...

Вы рекурсивно дважды ищете только в правом поддереве? Левое не интересует?

```
search_words(proot->right);         /////////

if (strlen(proot->word) >= NL) ...

search_words(proot->right);         /////////
```

И еще - не принципиально, но это плохой стиль - назвать функцию функцией поиска, но в ней еще и удалять...

Comment: Действительно, забыл заменить после копипаста, теперь все работает, спасибо.